# How do i check if both of these lists are unsorted? if its unsorted when i call the it it must return True

Tags: python, list, count, iteration

How do I check for unsorted string within the list? If it is unsorted the function called need to return true

```
list([['3C', 'AS', '2H']])
list([['0C', 'JH', 'QS', 'KH', '9D']])
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to check? Please add more details. Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
a = ['3C', 'AS', '2H']
b = ['0C', 'JH', 'QS', 'KH', '9D']

def sorted_or_not(lis):
    if lis != sorted(lis):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(sorted_or_not(a))
print(sorted_or_not(b))
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider rephrasing your question. I'm not sure what you mean
But one guess I have is that you want to check to see if a list has been sorted using the sorted() method:

```
ls = ['3C', 'AS', '2H']
ls2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

def is_sorted(listr):
    if listr == sorted(listr):
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(is_sorted(ls))
print(is_sorted(ls2))
```

Basically the same as the other answer (but they beat me to it!)